# NoClassDefFoundError with Tess4J

Tags: jar, tesseract, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to read text from an image with tesseract. I am importing the jar file as I don't know how to use maven. For some reason however, it is giving me a NoClassDefFoundError. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

I have attached the image of my code. [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY6JF.jpg)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

`test4j-3.4.8.jar` have compiled and test dependencies as you can see on this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/3.4.8). The `NoClassDefFoundError` is due to missing dependency that you forget to include in your program specifically for `com.sun.jna.Pointer` which is part of `jna-5.10.0.jar`.

If you will not use maven to import the jar file, make sure all dependencies are all included. But it's advisable to use maven to manage your dependencies so that you can avoid such related errors.